# How IE setting affect authorization

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a Webform app written in 
asp.net 4.5 and trying to understand how IE plays a role for authentication. So far my search has not provided a solid answer

I know webconfig setting override iis setting. But assume we set the authorization  mode to anonymous in both of  iis and web.config. can the IE Settings  override these?

For example if in IE we set Enable Integrated Windows Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" (which is the default), and the server requires integrated Windows authentication, then the user will be authenticated silently using current default credentials, if possible.

If you disable Integrated Windows Authentication, the user will be prompted to supply credentials.

See [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258063) for more info.

Comment: Please Give me one example where settings in IE determine the authentication(assuming you do not touch iis settings)

Comment: @SNash - Look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/06/integrated-windows-authentication-kerberos-ntlm-http-400-error-for-16kb-authorization-header.aspx  If you disable Integrated Windows Authentication, the browser will not use the Negotiate protocol.

Comment: Link you provided does not work. You said if you "disable Integrated Windows Authentication, the browser will not use the Negotiate protocol". How about the opposite?  That is IF you "enable Windows Authentication in the IIS " and then choose anonymous login in IE?

Comment: @SNash - What do you mean by "choose anonymous login in IE"?

Comment: Go to IE / Internet options/security/Custom level/User Authentication , there you see a n option as anonymous login.

Answer (score 1):

No, a browser can't possibly override server settings.

For example when Integrated Windows Authentication is active in the IIS, the server will ask the browser for credentials and expect a proper response. The browser can't override this, just respond - or not respond, causing the server to return relevant error code.

Comment: I'm sorry but still i'm not clear. Lets say in IE I have "Anonymous logon" and in IIS i have Form authentication. Which one has the effect?  If it is alway IIS then what's the point behind settings in the IE? Please  Give me one case where setting in IE determine the authentication